# Titanium: How to drag and drop images similar to Tinder

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm working on a Tinder clone and want to know how the Images can be drag and dropped. Any tutorial or links would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TiDraggable module:

https://github.com/moshemarciano/TiDraggable